# Structure of degree $n$ part of $Hom(\mathbb P^1, \mathbb P^1)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the Hom scheme $X=Hom(\mathbb P^1, \mathbb P^1)$ over an algebraically closed field $k$. Using deformation theory, I think we can show locally at a point representing  a degree $n$ morphism, $X$ is smooth of dimension $2n+1$.

So if we consider the subscheme $X_n$ of $X$ consist of degree $n$ morphisms, it has a natural action by $X_1 \times X_1=Aut(\mathbb P^1) \times  Aut(\mathbb P^1)= PGL(2) \times PGL(2)$ by composing morphism from left and right sides.

The question: is $X_n$ affine and connected? What is the quotient $X_n/PGL(2) \times PGL(2)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give a map $\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1$ of degree $n$ is equivalent to giving a pair of two homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ in two variables up to constant without common linear factors. This means that $X_n$ is an open subset of
$$
\bar{X}_n = \mathbb{P}^{2n+1}.
$$
This space $\bar{X}_n$ is called the *space of quasimaps* or the *Drinfeld compactification* of the space of maps.

Furthermore, it is clear that $\bar{X}_n \setminus X_n$ is the discriminant (of two polynomials) hypersurface, or equivalently the image of the natural map
$$
\bar{X}_{n-1} \times \mathbb{P}^1 \to \bar{X}_n
$$
that takes a pair of polynomials of degree $n-1$ and multiplies them by a common linear factor.

All this shows that $X_n$ is smooth and affine.

If $U$ and $V$ are two vector spaces of dimension 2 so that the source of the maps is $P(U)$ and the target is $P(V)$ then 
$$
\bar{X}_n = \mathbb{P}(V \otimes S^nU^*).
$$
This isomorphism is $PGL(U) \times PGL(V)$-equivariant.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there similiar result for $Hom(\mathbb P^n, \mathbb P^m)$?

Comment: And I am also quite interested in the action of $PGL_2 \times PGL_2$.

Comment: @zzy: I added a description of the group action. The formula $\mathbb{P}(V \otimes S^nU^*)$ still gives a compactification of the space of maps from $\mathbb{P}(U)$ to $\mathbb{P}(V)$ for $U$ and $V$ of any dimension, but the boundary has higher codimension, so the space of maps is no loner affine.

Comment: Thank you again!